# How to implement CMS in django?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, e-commerce, django-cms

I am building an E-commerce site. Now I am working on the product detail pages, how can I achieve the function that admin can write formated content (just like write something in MS word), then the front-end is able to display that content in its original format (paragraphs,fonts,maybe some pictures among it). Which library can do this? Thank you.

I am using django for back-end and react for front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/hiteshgarg14/how-to-integrate-custom-rich-text-editor-in-django-54czmp0gi), TinyMCE easily integrates with React have a look at their [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/), only downside is that it not a completely free tool advanced features require payment.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.